# this.props.parentFunction is not a function

Tags: reactjs

This is a simple React.js script, but couldn't find the cause. I think this issue is a common doubt for initial React developers. Please help.

The error showing is "*this.props.parentClick is not a function*".

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };

  }
  parentClick()  {

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <Test childClick={this.parentClick}/> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class Test extends Component{
   constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.childClick = this.childClick.bind(this);
   }
   childClick(){
     this.props.parentClick();
   }
   render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={()=>this.childClick()}>click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}  

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is the code in stackblitz.com.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3zt7qm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function inside of your Test component:

```
childClick(){
   this.props.parentClick();
}
```

should call `this.props.childClick()`, because thats the prop you passed into the Test component.

Answer (score 3):

Your prop is called `childClick` not `parentClick`

Try with:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };

  }
  parentClick()  {

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <Test parentClick={this.parentClick}/> // Here the name of your prop should be parentClick
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh:), simple mistake. After seeing your response, I found this also would work. Thanks for the hint.

`this.props.childClick();`